# why WPF combobox itemssource converter gets whole collection and not items?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

When I debug with following implementation. The Convert-method parameter value has all values and naturally the cast fails.

XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <appconv:CustomerNumberToStringConverter x:Key="customernumbertostringconverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<!-- ... -->
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerSearchNumbers, Converter={StaticResource customernumbertostringconverter}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomerSearchNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

VIEWMODEL

```
public enum CustomerIdentifier
{
    ClientPointNo = 0,
    ClientNo = 1,
    MeterNo = 2,
    CustPointNo = 3
}


public ObservableCollection<CustomerIdentifier> CustomerSearchNumbers { get; private set; }

CustomerSearchNumbers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerIdentifier>((IEnumerable<CustomerIdentifier>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(CustomerIdentifier)));
```

CONVERTER

```
public class CustomerNumberToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var enumValue = (CustomerIdentifier)value;
        switch (enumValue)
        {
            case CustomerIdentifier.ClientPointNo:
                return XxxUtility.GetString("strclientpointno");
            case CustomerIdentifier.ClientNo:
                return XxxUtility.GetString("strclientno");
            case CustomerIdentifier.MeterNo:
                return XxxUtility.GetString("strmeterno");
            default:
                return XxxUtility.GetString("strcustomerpointno");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how converters work - it allows you to convert the source item in the binding, which in this case is the `CustomerSearchNumbers`.  If you want to convert each individual item in the `ComboBox` then you want to specify a custom `ItemTemplate` that uses your converter:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerSearchNumbers}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource customernumbertostringconverter}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was sure that I been doing it like this before. Well... +1 for the only sensible answer: "Because that's how converters work" :)

Comment: @charm Keep in mind, you may need OneWay binding depending on your ItemSource property